# Wordpress qtranslate and qtranslate slug menu url wrong

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

qtranslate and qtranslate slug is not taking the correct language in url on menu side

The problem is that when I create the menu, the link is taking the language (EN/FR) but is not taking afer this the page title translated.

When I access page EN/page-en/ and FR/page-fr/ is ok but in the menu the links are build EN/page-en/ and FR/page-en/

Comment: This is not enough information to help you. But anyway. I developed a lot of wordpress site. When first somebody sad to me, it should be in multilanguage first i tried the qtranslate. The problem is with this, that this plugin is mess up the whole title, content, etc... After that, i tried WPML and that is using different posts for different languages. I suggest you to use WPML.

Comment: You might be lookig for [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-slug/).I would suggest you to use Polylang which do the same that @lolka_bolka suggested and its completely free.

Comment: Thank four feedback @lolka_bolka. I know the plugin but the issue is that I want to fix the issue with permalinks on this website because a friend asked me to do this for a short periode untill he decides on a new website. My issue is on permalink generation.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner. I am already using Qtranslate slug but is not working for permalinks on menu. The permalink itself is working good but is not working when I am creating the menu.

Comment: I have not used that plugin, but there might be option in setting or somewhere..

Comment: I've found a solution for this. I am using mqtranslate with qtranslate slug and some code optimizations to work like I wanted to.

Comment: There is no need to use two mqtranslate with qtranslate. You must have  done something wrong so you had to use both. But your post is not defining the problem with enough information to comment upon. Not how questions should be.